# Finding Actual Source Stacktrace When Using Webpack And Logging Errors

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using Webpack to bundle and minify my source code and trying to use the error object being passed to `window.onerror` to log client errors but `source`, `lineno`, `colno` and `stack` information all refer to the bundle JS file.

I can see the sourcemaps when debugging with Chrome developer tools. Is there a way to do this mapping on the client-side before sending the log data so that I can log the error with actual source file references?

Comment: [this blog post](https://medium.com/@petermikitsh/logging-client-side-javascript-stack-traces-86921532589) talks about a library called [retrace](https://github.com/fgnass/retrace) that is supposed to do what you're wanting